# Odd jQuery .insertAfter behaviour (messes up DOM structure completley)

Tags: jquery, html

No idea why, but

```
if ($(this).find(':nth-child(2)').is("span")) {
    var moveForward = $(this).find(".postInfo.forVideo");
$(this).find(':nth-child(2)').insertAfter(moveForward);
```

}

Is basically doing what it should, *but* it also changes the order of many other things. Like in a really really odd way.

It's hard to demo this via pasted code, i think just visually you'll be able to see the weirdness:

**Before**
[image]
**After**
[image]

As you can see, it's almost randomly pulling elements out of the div "postInfo forVideo".
You can see it here (for now, as this site is in development) here: http://syndex.me.

For example, why would it pull out the polygon element which is in the "pagecurl" div and then throw that after the span i'm working with? So odd!

Comment: you should check moveForward.length > 0 before inserting after it. Also consider wrapping your $(this) in a variable so you don't wrap it 3 times over and possibly mess up your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nth-child will select all elements that are the second child of their respective parent.  You probably just want the second child of the element.

```
var secondChild = $(this).children().eq(2);
if (secondChild.is("span")) {
    var moveForward = $(this).find(".postInfo.forVideo");
    secondChild.insertAfter(moveForward);
```

Comment: Ahh, i feel like a dope. That's what you get for googling "select second child jquery" without double checking.